# modifying one dimensional array into two dimensional with new values

Tags: php

i have the following array:

```
$list = array('item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6');
```

i need to take this array and break it into smaller arrays within 1 array for a program.  Each small array needs to have '999999' at index 0, followed by the next 2 items in the `$list` array, then followed by the same 2 items in the `$list` array, but with `.pdf` at the end,  to create a filename.  So the final result would be like this:

```
$newList = array( array(999999, "item1" , "item2", "item1.pdf", "item2.pdf"),
               array(999999, "item3" , "item4", "item3.pdf", "item4.pdf"),
               array(999999, "item5" , "item6", "item5.pdf", "item6.pdf")
             );
```

the original list array may contain up to 100 values at sometimes.  What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why must the array contain static and duplicate values?

Comment: its because it gets used in a printing press.  the first 2 values after 999999 is the file name, the next 2 is the actual file.  its how  our press works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_splice` to remove 2 elements at each iteration and build your results array. Something like that:

```
$list = array('item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6');

$result = array();
while (!empty($list)) {
    $array = array_splice($list, 0, 2);

    if (count($array) == 2) {
        $result[] = array(999999, $array[0], $array[1], $array[0] . ".pdf", $array[1] . ".pdf");
    } else {
        $result[] = array(999999, $array[0], '', $array[0] . ".pdf", '');
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I was curious to try it :)

Comment: thanks for the help.  last question, if the original array has odd number of values, the last array value is just a `.pdf`.  is there away to have it not create an array value with just the extension?

Comment: beautiful.  i appreciate the help.  it all makes sense to me

Answer (score 1):

As a start, take a look at [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

You could add the static elements (`999999`, `*.pdf`) to the result with some custom code. But at that point a solution such as the one provided by **Mathieu Imbert** is a better option.

**Note:** PHP has over a hundred [array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). Learning these will make you a [better PHP developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: +1 for the note about array functions. Combined with anonymous callbacks, those functions can greatly improve any array-handling code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `each` and a normal while loop:

```
// solution without an array_* function                                                                    
$newList = array();                                                         
while((list(,$a) = each($list)) && (list(,$b) = each($list))) {             
    $newList[] = array(999999, $a, $b, "$a.pdf", "$b.pdf");                 
}                                                                           

print_r($newList);
```

or no loop at all (requires PHP >= 5.3):

```
$newList = array_map(function($e) {                                         
    return array(999999, $e[0], $e[1], "{$e[0]}.pdf", "{$e[1]}.pdf");       
}, array_chunk($list, 2));                                                  

print_r($newList);
```